# How should I layout my Activity?

Tags: android, layout, animation, android-layout, android-animation

I have an activity with a grid of 3x4 Button. See the image below. When the user touches one of the buttons the button is animated.

The button moves from its current location to the center of the screen holds and then returns to its original position. While its doing this the button is also growing to fill the screen, holds and then shrinks back down to its original size.

During the animation no other buttons should move.

Originally I coded this up using an AbsoluteLayout, however, as this layout is deprecated I'd like to use a different layout, but I'm not sure which one to use.

Is there a better way to layout this activity while still allowing me to achieve the described behavior, and if so what layout should I use and how should I structure it?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Animation leaves lines during movement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392279/android-animation-leaves-lines-during-movement)

Comment: not actually a duplicate, rather a different question about the same application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to go with the AbsoluteLayout

Comment: Isn't AbsoluteLayout deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

use a gridlayout, that seems to make the most sense from what your picture looks like.

Comment: If I move around one of the buttons will it not also push around the other buttons in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a RelativeLayout but without aligning the buttons to each other with above/below/leftOf/rightOf.

By the way, isn't this question related to your other question: [Android Animation leaves lines during movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392279/android-animation-leaves-lines-during-movement)

Anyway, as I already said I would use a RelativeLayout, place the buttons as required by setting their marginLeft/marginTop values accordingly. This leaves the buttons independent of each other.

Then in your animation code change the margin and dimension values of the current button as required.

Comment: it is somewhat related, the other question is about the animation errors, this question is specifically trying to figure out how to not use the deprecated AbsoluteLayout